# This window doesn't have void client data

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

Все хорошо работало, но после компиляции одного из приложений начала появляться следующая ошибка:

> assert "m_clientDataType != wxClientData_Object" failed in DoClientData(): this window doen't have void client data.

[image: Экранный снимок диалогового окна с сообщением об ошибке]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема была в конфликтах компилятора с антивирусом. Я переустановил компилятор и все заработало.

Comment: Но потом антивирус опять портил компилятор. все наладилось лишь когда удалил антивирус.